# How to make failed command substitution exit shell when it's in a environment variable

Tags: bash, shell

This code works as expected

```
set -e
a="$(exit 1)"
echo hi
```

Nothing is printed.

But if the command substitution happens in an environment variable

```
set -e
a="$(exit 1)" echo hi
```

Then bash doesn't exit early and `hi` is printed.

I know I can make it work by doing

```
set -e
a="$(exit 1)"
a="$a" echo hi
```

Is there a flag or something that makes bash directly fail without me having to rewrite my code?

Comment: Use a *compound command*, e.g. `a="$(exit 1)" && echo hi` (though why you are assigning the result of the command substitution is unclear)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I think that no longer passes `a` as an env var to `echo`?

Comment: See [BashFAQ #105: Why doesn't set -e (or set -o errexit, or trap ERR) do what I expected?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105)

Answer (score 0):

```
:=>cat temp.ksh
set -e
a="$(exit 1)" && echo hi
:=>./temp.ksh
:=>cat temp_1.ksh
set -e
a="$(exit 0)" && echo hi
:=>./temp_1.ksh
hi
:=>
```

Explanation :

`&&` operator is used for binding commands. It check the status of command on the left and execute command on right if success.

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.

Comment: Thank you @borchvm  . I will try to add explanation hence forth.

Comment: As I replied in the question's comments, I don't think this passes `a` as an env var to `echo` anymore

Comment: Could please explain your requirements ?